Existence of a $p$-regular subgraph: is it true for $p=6$?
It's well known that any loopless graph $G = (V,E)$ with average degree bigger than $2p − 2$ and maximum degree at most $2p − 1$ contains a $p$-regular subgraph for any prime power $p$.
But we don't know if it is true for all integers $p$.
As an example or counterexample, I want to check the case with $p=6$, but it is not so easy.

Isn't a loopless graph a forest, and therefore the average degree is always $\leq 1$?

@BillBradley I think “loopless” here means no self-links $(i,i)$ rather than no cycles.
